# Is it ok to use Otto outside android?

Tags: jakarta-ee, bus, otto

I am working on a Java EE project that constantly talks to a webservice, I have some experience using Otto on Android and I was wondering if would be ok if I add it to this project too. What you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otto was forked from Google's Guava [Event Bus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) which is aimed at pure Java. Of course, there are certain constraints with using an event bus in a JavaEE environment. You may find that JMS is a better approach.